# Split arrays in dataframe to several columns in Python (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Summary:

I extracted the header from the CSV file:

```
df_col = [df.columns[0]] #Parte diario 17 de marzo
```

Outcome:

I want to create new columns for each word from the string extracted from the HEADER (Parte diario 17 de marzo):

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5 0 Parte diario 17 de marzo
```

Problem:

I am trying to use this code, but it does not work:

```
df_col_2['Día'] = df_col_2[0].str.split()
```

Does someone know how to split the array into separate columns?

Comment: Have you tried `...str.split(expand=True)`? See [The documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html)

Comment: Or how about you put it into the list and do list.split?

Comment: ...str.split(expand=True) > this does NOT work, can it be because the string contains a number "17"?

Comment: what is df_col_2? does it have [0] column? or something named (like "Col1")?

Comment: import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('cob.csv')
df_col = [df.columns[0]]
df_col.str.split(expand=True)